# Resizing images with variant method creates broken image icon in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I am new to rails and I am adding an avatar image to my app, but when I try to resize it in my `ApplicationHelper` using the `variant` method the image appears as a broken image icon, I don't understand why this is other than it might have to do with the pipeline

Here is a picture of whats happening:
[image]

`application_helper.rb`

```
module ApplicationHelper
  require "mini_magick"

  def avatar_url_for(user, opts = {})
    size = opts[:size || 32]

    if user.avatar.attached?
      user.avatar.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100])
    else
      hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(user.email.downcase)
      "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}.png?s=#{size}"
    end
  end
 end
```

`_navbar.html.erb`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Facebook</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria- 
expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
  <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href= "/">Home</a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href= "users/<%= current_user.id 
%>"  >Profile</a>
  </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/pages/friends"><i class="bi 
  bi-people"></i></a>
  </li>
    
    
  </ul>
  <ul class="navbar-nav" >
  
  <% if current_user %>
  
      <%= link_to user_path(current_user.id), class: "nav-link" do %>
    
    <%= image_tag avatar_url_for(current_user, size: 32), class: "rounded-circle mr- 
1" %>
 
    <% end %>

  </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
  Logged in as <%= current_user.username %>
  
<% end %>
</ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
  
  <% if current_user %>
   
  <%= link_to(destroy_user_session_path, {:class => "nav-link", :method => :delete}) 
do  %>
    <span class="sidebar-normal"> Logout </span>
<% end %>
<% end %>
  
  </ul>

  <ul class="navbar-nav">
  
    <%= render 'layouts/notifications' %>
  
  </ul>

  <form class="d-flex" role="search">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria- 
  label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to run `sudo apt-get install libvips` to add [libvips](https://github.com/libvips/libvips) dependencies that were missing.

The method [`#resize_to_limit`](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/aed5b80cd739eb3164c2f165ee1a9bdd392acc79/lib/image_processing/vips.rb#L67-L71) is from the [image_processing](https://github.com/janko/image_processing) gem which [relies](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/blob/aed5b80cd739eb3164c2f165ee1a9bdd392acc79/image_processing.gemspec#L20) on the [ruby-vips](https://github.com/libvips/ruby-vips) gem which relies on having [libvips](https://www.libvips.org/install.html) installed.

Comment: CoolGuy, please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The "Post Answer" button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Answer (score 2):

To resize images ActiveStorage uses third-party libraries, by default

- **libvips** (in rails >= 7)
- **ImageMagick** (in rails < 7)

To install on Mac

```
brew install imagemagick
```

or

```
brew install vips
```

On Ubuntu based OS

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```

or

```
sudo apt install libvips
```

You also need in your `Gemfile`

```
gem "image_processing"
```

On Heroku there is no libvips package. To activate it you need create `Aptfile` with [such content](https://github.com/janko/image_processing/issues/32)

```
libglib2.0-0
libglib2.0-dev
libpoppler-glib8
libheif-dev
libvips-dev
libvips
```